# Replace any chunk of string to a singular instance in Python

Tags: python, string

For example if

```
s = "111111111111234"
or
s = "1111234"
or
s = "jsdfjkdsnfkjds111jknsdjkfsd"
or
s = "111as1as11"
```

I want to reduce any contiguous chunk of 1's to a single 1.

```
1234
1234
jsdfjkdsnfkjds1jknsdjkfsd
1as1as1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.sub`

```
import re
s = '111111111111234'
print re.sub('1+', '1', s)
# '1234'
```

Explanation:

- `'1+'` - the `+` matches one or more repetitions of the previous regex
  (in this case `1`)
- `'1'` - tells `re.sub` what to replace it with.
- `s` - the string to perform the `re.sub` on.

Comment: So I take it the + means "any contiguous instance of"? If I were to do "++" it would replace contiguous "+" signs?

Comment: You need to escape it, so it would be "\\++".

Comment: Is that the only character that would require escaping in this context? (I guess this is a good excuse for me to go learn regular expressions in Python...)

Comment: Not sure. Depends on the intended effect.

Comment: You need to escape any character that would otherwise have a special meaning (eg. `*, ?, +, ^` etc.)

Comment: @AgainstASicilian Python regexes are the same as everyone else's.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
re.sub('(.)\\1+', "\\1", "1111122233334444")
#=> "1234"
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and Volatility's answer (i.e. what does that additional syntax do?)

Comment: @Volatility's answer is better if you only want to replace a specific character. Mine replaces any repeated character. The \\1 is a backreference to the first group, the (.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.groupby()`:

```
In [162]: from itertools import groupby

In [163]: strs="111111111111234"

In [164]: "".join(k if k=='1' else "".join(g) for k,g in groupby(strs))
Out[164]: '1234'

In [170]: strs="1111112222111111234"

In [171]: "".join(k if k=='1' else "".join(g) for k,g in groupby(strs))
Out[171]: '122221234'
```

or to reduce all repeated items to single item:

```
In [175]: strs="1111112222111111234"

In [176]: "".join(k for k,g in groupby(strs))
Out[176]: '121234'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` to get rid of duplicates, then `join` the resulting list:

```
>>> ''.join(set('11111234'))
'1324'
```

Comment: Won't work for any of the requested examples. `set` destroys the order of the original.